# openni ros-fuerte ubuntu 12.04 anyone?

Tags: ros, openni, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.
I have posted a couple of questions already considering execution of

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

in ubuntu 12.04 under ros fuerte. It produces plenty of errors, that you may find in threads: [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/35536/ros-fuerte-opennilaunch-unable-to-find-usb-device/) and [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/36043/weird-behavior-of-rviz-ros-fuerte/)

Though, now I'm not asking to dig into anything.

I would really like to know if there actually **are any people** who are able to use the command provided above in ros fuerte under ubuntu 12.04 or alike?

Thanks. Waiting for your responses.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37125/openni-ros-fuerte-ubuntu-12.04-anyone?/) by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2012-06-23

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Em, as far as I know this bug was fixed. I am able to get the ASUS Kinect to work on my laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte on it.

---

Originally posted by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) with karma: 386 on 2012-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, but only sporadically.  At first, it didn't work at all, but one day after an update to ubuntu and a restart, it started to work again. It occasionally won't start and throws an exception. Sometimes it won't stop with ctrl^C if it is running. I can usually kill Xnsensorserver a couple of times and it'll work for a while again.

I've documented all my findings and crazy hypotheses in [my question](http://answers.ros.org/question/33622/openni_launch-not-working-in-fuerte-ubuntu-precise/).  The best answer so far (by lubosz) is to use the unstable/avin2 branches of openni and the primesense driver.  Apparently, they don't have the bugs that the official one does.  I've been meaning to try that out, but haven't had time yet.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on 2012-06-26**:
Thanks for the tip. I think I'll check that out in a couple of days.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-06-26**:
I tested Ubuntu 12.04 + Fuerte, but as tbh said, roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch was working only sporadically.

I had to go back to Ubuntu 11.10 + Electric as openni is an essential part of my project.

**Comment by [Victor Gonzalez-Pacheco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2660/victor-gonzalez-pacheco/) on 2012-07-04**:
Thanks for the answer. I also had to go back to Electric in 11.10. I will try to upgrade in a couple of months or so.